# JavaScript menu control sub-menu

Tags: javascript, css

I use this javascript to control a menu dropdown.

Is it possible to tell the script always to display sub-menus - but only if there are any?
Hope someone can help.

Ex code: http://jsfiddle.net/zQU7H/

Comment: I removed the "java" tag from this question.

Comment: @Diodeus: Debatable... you probably want `Java !== JavaScript` to be sure

Comment: I'm looking at your jsFiddle, and I'm not sure what you're looking for.  Do you just want to make it conditional on the number of li children?  Should all the sub menus display for all the items?

Comment: Hey Brian, yes i want the sub menues to be displayd if there are any - now they disaper when i enter a new page. is there a way to force the sub-memu to appear when one of them are active

Comment: the jsfiddle sample need jquery (mootools set by default left side)

Comment: i think by simulating the hover when it's the same url like in this [link](http://www.kevinleary.net/highlighting-the-current-page-with-php-jquery/)

Comment: yes - it works with jquery, but i still need the sub menu (if any) to be shown - also when i enter a new page Hope you can help! - se ex.: http://jsfiddle.net/zQU7H/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED TO MEET NEEDS EXPLAINED ON COMMENTS**

After understanding what you need (please, next time try to explain your question a little better), here is a and updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zQU7H/6/) that mgiht help you. In this case I supossed (correct me if I'm wrong) that ou don't use link with hashes in your site, and what it does is search for a hash at url, this hash, should be equal to the title of the a element (you can highlight it) you'll like to show submenu of. Example:

`<a title="Bestilling" href="http://www.example.com/mypage.html#Handelsbetingelser"></a>`

You can do this manually or with jquery:

```
$("#productNav ul li").each(function(){
    var title = $(this).children("a").attr("title");
    $(this).find("li a").attr("href",function(index,oldattr){
        return oldattr+"#"+title;
    });
});
```

This code will add a hashtag and the title menu parent.

**ORIGINAL**

I don't know if I understood your question right, but in case it helps, I've updated khaled_webdevs Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zQU7H/5/.

It just show one submenu at a time, and changes it if another one should be shown. On this example I made the first element with submenu to be shown, but you can remove that and make any submenu you wan't to show at first by addign to it the class "current".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey - thanks for you help, it almost seems to work, but when I click on one of the menu items after the first ex. 'Handelsbetingelser' or one of sub-menus the menu jump back to show the first sub-menus in the menu under 'Forside'.
 If I point the mouse over the 'Handelsbetingelser', the menu pops up fine and stays there ....
 hmmm - you have some ideas to fiks it?

Comment: So you're trying to keep the submenu show before a page "reload" and after a page "reload", am I right? With reload I mean that when you click in any element of the maenu the page changes an the menu is reloaded. Is it correct?

Comment: Hey Aitor, yes that is exactly what I want... - Can you help: o)

Answer (score 0):

i have added a class current to simulate active link to li

http://jsfiddle.net/zQU7H/2/

not a final solution maybe

Comment: Hey thanks, but it still disaper when i select one of the sub menu. se ex.: http://jsfiddle.net/zQU7H/3/